# How can I convert a string representation of binary notation to actual binary notation

Tags: python-2.7

so I've been playing around with a 20x4 Character LCD display recently with my Raspberry Pi and Python 2.7. I've been driving it using the RPLCD library found here https://github.com/dbrgn/RPLCD. In the test_20x4.py source they create custom characters using a series of what appears to be binary notations. For example, to create a happy face character:

```
happy = (0b00000, 0b01010, 0b01010, 0b00000, 0b10001, 0b10001, 0b01110, 0b00000)
```

This represents 8 rows, 5 column character. Now, I wrote a GUI with my son using Tkinter and one of the things we want to do is have the user create their own custom characters. What I have now is a string representation of each one of the series, for example:

```
'0b00000'
```

can I convert this back to binary notation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> int('0b10101', 2)
21
```